# apt-get update and package authentication

Tags: package-management, apt, authentication, ssl

Sometimes when you try to apt-get install a program, you get a warning message about how some packages couldn't be authenticated.

Doing an apt-get update will sometimes fix the problem, but sometimes it won't.

How does apt-get update fix this problem?

Does this type of authentication necessarily involve ssl?

Why does it sometimes not fix the problem?

Comment: Are you using Debian or some derived distro? What 3rd party repositories? What is the exact error message? Help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, each package is signed using GPG. Keys are provided through different Debian packages ([look for `*-keyring` packages](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=keyring&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all)).
You can see currently installed keys using `apt-key`.

Additional keys are used when you are using 3rd party repositories such as Ubuntu PPA or others (Google, Skype, Valve...).

Some 3rd party repositories may also contain *not* signed packages which lead into this apt warning. Be particularly careful when using these repositories as a malicious Debian package you install can definitively compromise your system.

See [this page](http://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt) (apt-secure) for more information.

Regarding `apt-get update` effect on this, it retrieves from the server up-to-date information regarding packages which can fix previous errors such as unsigned packages, expired GPG key and other bugs that may break the authentification chain.